# Download a giant file with HTTP and upload to FTP server without storing it

Tags: python, stream, ftp

I have a project which I should download some giant files using HTTP and upload them to am FTP server. The simplest way is to first download the file and then upload it to FTP; Thinking it as two independent stages.

But can we use streams to upload the file as it is being downloaded? This way seems more efficient. Any example specially in python are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`requests` module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) to obtain a file-like object representing the HTTP download and use it with [ftplib `FTP.storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary):

```
from ftplib import FTP
import requests 

url = "https://www.example.com/file.zip"
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
ftp = FTP(host, user, passwd)
ftp.storbinary("STOR /ftp/path/file.zip", r.raw)
```